# Do I need to destroy stream in Promise.all loop when happens error

Tags: node.js, stream

I have the following pseudo code that shows a case where one of my threads inside Promise.all gets an unexpected error. In the finished code, I deal with this, but I noticed (which seems to be logical) the following: despite the fact that the Promise.all break with an error and it no longer waits for the result of each promise inside, the event handlers of my stream continue to receive and process data. Accordingly, do I understand correctly that in the final block I should remove all listeners and destroy the stream.
I use node.js v8.17

```
function createReadStream(filename) {
    // Imagine that we return readable stream;
    return filename;
}

function someFn(filenames) {
    const streams = new Set();
    try {
        return await Promise.all(filenames.map(filename => {
            const readstream = createReadStream(filename);
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                readstream.on('error', reject);
                readstream.on('data', onData);
                readstream.on('close', resolve);
                throw new Error('Unexpected error');
            });
        }));
    } finally {
        streams.forEach((stream) => {
            stream.removeAllListeners('data').removeAllListeners('close').destroy();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise.all()` does not control or affect the individual asynchronous operations that it is monitoring - it is just watching them.  So, once you start those asynchronous operations and then pass the promises to `Promise.all()`, those individual asynchronous operations run on their own - `Promise.all()` does not influence them in any way.

If one of the asynchronous operations rejects quickly, then `Promise.all()` will see that rejection and will immediately reject its own promise.  But, meanwhile, the other asynchronous operations just keep on trucking doing whatever it is they were originally doing.

So, each individual asynchronous operation just needs to clean up after itself.   When each individual one resolves or rejects, it just needs to clean up for itself.  That burden should NOT be placed on the `Promise.all()` caller.

Now, there could be some coding situation where as soon as one promise rejects, you want to somehow "abort" the other asynchronous operations.  For example, if one of the asynchronous operations was a timeout timer, you might want to abort that timer with a `clearTimeout()`, but that's not a general purpose thing, that's very specific to exactly what the actual asynchronous operations are and whether there even is a need and ability to abort.

> Accordingly, do I understand correctly that in the final block I should remove all listeners and destroy the stream. I use node.js v8.17

You do not need to do this on streams that complete normally.  Depending upon the circumstances of a failure and how exactly you've coded your stream code, you may or may not need to do some cleanup work for a stream when there's an error.

Comment: Thank you, you told me everything I wanted to know. The only thing that is not entirely clear to me is your proposal "That burden should NOT be placed on the Promise.all() caller.". If you could show what you mean in the code, I would appreciate it!

Comment: @whyamideadatcyber - If any given promise has cleanup work to do on a rejection, it should have it's own `.catch()`, do the cleanup work, then rethrow the error.  Ideally, this happens a layer lower so the caller can just field the rejection and not have to worry about cleanup because the promise that rejected cleaned things up itself appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think I get it now!